# Google Query - Show TOTAL Row as blank or 0% cells if Query table returns empty rows or #VALUE! error

Tags: stack, google-sheets-formula, average, google-query-language

I am calculating a TOTAL's row for an FTR table that i want to stack below the FTR table like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(
{
 FTR Table ;
 TOTAL
}
```

The FTR Table is also calculated via Google Query. The table contains some cells having 0%. For a particular Year, say 2018 (Cell C1), the FTR Table may look like below:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|  FTR %   | 2018-Jan | 2018-Feb | 2018-Mar | 2018-Apr | 2018-May | 2018-Jun | 2018-Jul | 2018-Aug | 2018-Sep | 2018-Oct | 2018-Nov | 2018-Dec |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Allana   |          |          |          |          |          |          |          | 0.00%    |          | 76.92%   | 85.00%   | 83.72%   |
| Mark     |          |          |          | 0.00%    |          |          | 0.00%    | 75.00%   | 86.21%   | 76.32%   | 90.16%   | 91.43%   |
| Jane     |          | 57.50%   | 68.97%   | 89.47%   | 81.82%   | 81.36%   | 91.11%   | 90.24%   | 85.71%   | 88.89%   | 82.69%   | 89.61%   |
| Santorin |          |          |          | 0.00%    |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |
| Lamaiye  |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          | 85.71%   |
| Suez     | 80.00%   |          | 86.67%   | 75.00%   | 81.08%   | 87.27%   | 91.80%   | 79.69%   | 81.43%   | 81.40%   | 71.70%   | 76.00%   |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

and the TOTAL row may show as AVERAGE % of each Year-Month Column :

```
+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| TOTAL | 80.00% | 57.50% | 77.82% | 82.24% | 81.45% | 84.31% | 91.46% | 81.64% | 84.45% | 80.88% | 82.39% | 85.29% |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Note: See `2018-July` & `2018-Aug` where there are 0%'s but the AVERAGE is calculated correctly.

`2018-July = 91.46%`
`2018-Aug =  81.64%`

But for a particular Year 2017, the table may just show 0% and blank Column Headers also, to maintain Column structure of the stacked tables (one above the other).

```
+-------+--+--+--+----------+----------+
| FTR % |  |  |  | 2017-Aug | 2017-Dec |
+-------+--+--+--+----------+----------+
| Mark  |  |  |  |          | 0.00%    |
| Jane  |  |  |  | 0.00%    |          |
+-------+--+--+--+----------+----------+
```

However, the problem arises here for the TOTAL row as it results in

```
+---------+
| #VALUE! |
+---------+
```

with error description: `Error:Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC`

This single cell value for the `TOTAL row` breaks the Tables Column structure and the above stacked Tables e.g. the FTR Table also does not show up. I need to have some way to show the TOTAL row Column cells as `BLANKS` or `0%'s` (like as shown below) whenever there is such kind of error:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| TOTAL | 0.00% | 0.00% | 0.00% | 0.00% | 0.00% |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I cannot share any Spreadsheet due to legal restrictions on my laptop, so I am pasting the Google Query for the TOTAL's row only as it is similar to the FTR table, except for a few changes:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY({QUERY(
 {TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy-mmm;;")&"♦"&'Study Report'!N1:N, 'Study Report'!B1:F, TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy;;"), TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy-mm;;"), 'Study Report'!H1:T, TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy-mm;;")&
 IF('Study Report'!G1:G="",,"♥"&TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G, "yyyy-mmm;;"))},"select Col1,Col8,Col15,Col22,count(Col2) where Col8 is not null and Col7 = '"&C1&"' and Col13 != 'Cancelled' group by Col1,Col8,Col15,Col22 order by Col8"),

IFNA(VLOOKUP(QUERY({TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy-mmm;;")&"♦"&'Study Report'!N1:N, 'Study Report'!B1:F, TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy;;"), TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy-mm;;"), 'Study Report'!H1:T, TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy-mm;;")&IF('Study Report'!G1:G="",,"♥"&TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G, "yyyy-mmm;;"))}, 
 "select Col1,Col8,Col15,Col22,count(Col2) where Col8 is not null and Col7 = '"&C1&"' and Col13 != 'Cancelled' group by Col1,Col8,Col15,Col22 order by Col8")
,QUERY({TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy-mmm;;")&"♦"&'Study Report'!N1:N, 'Study Report'!B1:F, TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy;;"), TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy-mm;;"), 'Study Report'!H1:T, TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy-mm;;")&
 IF('Study Report'!G1:G="",,"♥"&TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G, "yyyy-mmm;;"))}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col2) where Col8 is not null and Col7 = '"&C1&"' and Col13 != 'Cancelled' and Col16!= 'NO - all fine' AND Col16!='-' group by Col8,Col1")
,2,0))
}
,"SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,(1-Col6/Col5 * 1) WHERE (1-Col6/Col5 * 1)>0 label Col1 'A', Col2 'B', Col3 'C', Col4 'D', (1-Col6/Col5 * 1) 'diff'"),
"SELECT Col4, AVG(Col5) GROUP BY Col4 LABEL AVG(Col5) 'TOTAL' FORMAT AVG(Col5) '0.00%'"),"SELECT Col2")))
```

*Credits: Thanks to @player0 for showing me this method of Stacking Tables whilst maintaining the Column structure.*

**EDIT:**

I tried the below solution with an IFERROR() function (also shown earlier by @Player0, which adds a blank row between two tables), for generating the TOTAL row if no data or on error:

```
=TRANSPOSE(
QUERY(
TRANSPOSE(

IFERROR(
ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY({QUERY( {TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy-mmm;;")&"♦"&'Study Report'!N1:N, 'Study Report'!B1:F, TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy;;"), TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy-mm;;"), 'Study Report'!H1:T, TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy-mm;;")& IF('Study Report'!G1:G="",,"♥"&TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G, "yyyy-mmm;;"))},"select Col1,Col8,Col15,Col22,count(Col2) where Col8 is not null and Col7 = '"&C1&"' and Col13 != 'Cancelled' group by Col1,Col8,Col15,Col22 order by Col8"), IFNA(VLOOKUP(QUERY({TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy-mmm;;")&"♦"&'Study Report'!N1:N, 'Study Report'!B1:F, TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy;;"), TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy-mm;;"), 'Study Report'!H1:T, TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy-mm;;")&IF('Study Report'!G1:G="",,"♥"&TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G, "yyyy-mmm;;"))}, "select Col1,Col8,Col15,Col22,count(Col2) where Col8 is not null and Col7 = '"&C1&"' and Col13 != 'Cancelled' group by Col1,Col8,Col15,Col22 order by Col8") ,QUERY({TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy-mmm;;")&"♦"&'Study Report'!N1:N, 'Study Report'!B1:F, TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy;;"), TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy-mm;;"), 'Study Report'!H1:T, TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy-mm;;")& IF('Study Report'!G1:G="",,"♥"&TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G, "yyyy-mmm;;"))}, "select Col1,count(Col2) where Col8 is not null and Col7 = '"&C1&"' and Col13 != 'Cancelled' and Col16!= 'NO - all fine' AND Col16!='-' group by Col8,Col1") ,2,0)) } ,"SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,(1-Col6/Col5 * 1) WHERE (1-Col6/Col5 * 1)>0 label Col1 'A', Col2 'B', Col3 'C', Col4 'D', (1-Col6/Col5 * 1) 'diff'"), "SELECT Col4, AVG(Col5) GROUP BY Col4 LABEL AVG(Col5) 'TOTAL' FORMAT AVG(Col5) '0.00%'"),"SELECT Col2 FORMAT Col2 '0.00%'"))),


ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REPT("TOTAL ♠", COLUMNS(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy-mmm;;")&"♦"&'Study Report'!N1:N, 'Study Report'!B1:F, TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy;;"), TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy-mm;;"), 'Study Report'!H1:T, TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G,"yyyy-mm;;")& IF('Study Report'!G1:G="",,"♥"&TEXT('Study Report'!G1:G, "yyyy-mmm;;"))},"select Col22,count(Col2) where Col8 is not null and Col7 = '"&C1&"' and Col13 != 'Cancelled' group by Col22")))), "♠") ))),"SELECT Col1 FORMAT Col1 '0.00%'"))
```

The Only issue is that all the Values will show the word `TOTAL` for all cells, instead of only 1st cell and rest cells as 0.00%:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| TOTAL  | TOTAL  | TOTAL  | TOTAL  | TOTAL  | TOTAL  |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Any better idea instead to show it like below:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| TOTAL | 0.00% | 0.00% | 0.00% | 0.00% | 0.00% |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: wrap your whole formula into IFERROR() so if an error occurs it will show nothing

Comment: @player0, since i want to maintain above stacked tables from collapsing, i need to show blank or 0.00% cells for the columns. I hope you understand as you showed me the HLOOKUP trick to add missing columns.

Comment: @player0 see my edit section in post.